# Cannot send email using AWS SES via Node.js app running on EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

Setup: Node.js app running on EC2 Linux box. No outbound rules currently defined

Goal: To allow Node.js app to send email using AWS SES (via aws-sdk).

Issue: Cannot send email(running into timeout errors)

How should I go about setting up the EC2 security to *only* allow sending of emails via AWS SES?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [troubleshoot SMTP timeout issues with Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/smtp-connectivity-timeout-issues-ses/) document from AWS.